# Replace a data sequence with another in an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I would need to replace some data sequences with others, in an array, such as in this example (whose signature I imagined for the replacement function):

```
seq_replace(
    int *array, size_t size0,      // The array to modify         + its size
    int *to_replace, size_t size1, // The sequence to be replaced + its size
    int *to_place, size_t size2);  // The sequence to be placed   + its size

int array[] = {0, 6, 3, 0, 6, 2};
seq_replace(
    &array, 6,
    (const int[]){0, 6}, 2,
    (const int[]){9}, 1);
```

And would be obtain my `array` with values `{9, 3, 9, 2}`.

I imagine that linked lists would be more suitable for this style of task, but I work throughout my project with arrays, and making conversions between types of container would cost time.

Anyway, I don't know of any algorithm to do this kind of thing, and I haven't found anything interesting on the Internet either. I therefore turn to this site for advice on how to carry out this task.

Comment: Not enough precise.. Can `to_place` be longer than `to_replace` ? If yes, what behavior is expected ? In your example, what is the result of replacing {0,6} by {7,8,9} ? Or {2} by {4,5} ?

Comment: Any length of `to_replace` and `to_place` should be possible. In your examples, replacing `{0, 6}` with `{7, 8, 9}` would give this: `{7, 8, 9, 3, 7, 8, 9, 2}`. Or replace `{2}` with `{4, 5}` would give this: `{0, 6, 3, 0, 6, 4, 5}`... So there is a resizing of the array, which reminds me of an implementation track, where we would not directly modify the array, but create a temporary one. I'm going to see if there's a way to do it like that.

Comment: if size2 > size1 and if you want to do all replacement, the resulting array is larger than the initial. Either you know there is enough space after size0 (this is not the case of your example) or you need to dynamically allocate (malloc) a new table. Or do you think you receive a dynamically allocated table (in that case we can do a realloc() on it) ?
In any case, if you (re)allocate the table you need to return the new pointer and also the new size, so the current signature of seq_replace is not good.
Try to tell us exactly what you want.

Comment: what is the problem you encounter

Comment: I see... I may be doing it wrong for what I want to do, but I would like to make a toy peephole optimizer for a series of instructions on a stack. For example, replace unnecessary instructions such as `dup swap` with `dup`, or `swap swap` by `<nothing>`.

I don't see how else to do it, actually.

Comment: If it is a toy program, you can either assume your initial array is physically large enough for any replacement or it is mallocated and can be extended.

Comment: This won't work if size1 and size2 are different, as arrays in C are fixed size and cannot be resized -- you can only reallocate to create a new array of a different size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that works in the case `array` is known to be large enough for any replacement. The function returns the new logical size of `array`. The `// p += size2;` commented instruction makes it possible to recursively replace inside the result of `to_place` (as it is the case for a peephole optimizer). For instance in {0,6,6} replacing {0,6} by {0} gives {0}.

There is a `main()` to test various cases.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void show_array(const int *array, size_t size0)
{
 int i;
  for(i = 0; i < size0; i++)
    printf("%3d", array[i]);
  puts("");
}

int seq_replace(int *array, size_t size0,            // The array to modify         + its size
                const int *to_replace, size_t size1, // The sequence to be replaced + its size
                const int *to_place, size_t size2)   // The sequence to be placed   + its size
{
  int *p = array, *end = array + size0;

  while(p < end)
    {
      if (p + size1 <= end && memcmp(p, to_replace, size1 * sizeof(*p)) == 0)
        {
          memmove(p + size2, p + size1, (end - p - size1) * sizeof(*p));
          memcpy(p, to_place, size2 * sizeof(*p));
          // p += size2; // uncomment to avoid replacements in to_place itself
          size0 = size0 - size1 + size2;
          end = array + size0;
        }
      else
        {
          p++;
        }
    }
  return size0; // return logical new size
}

#define N_ELEM(p) (sizeof(p) / sizeof(*(p)))

// array is physically large enough
int array[1000] = {0, 6, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, 6, 0, 6};
int size0 = 10; // its logical length
int to_replace[] = {0, 6};
int to_place[] = {0}; // try {9, 8}, {9, 8, 7}, {9} and even {}

int main()
{

  printf("initial array; length: %d\n", size0);
  show_array(array, size0);

  size0 = seq_replace(array, size0,
                      to_replace, N_ELEM(to_replace),
                      to_place, N_ELEM(to_place));

  printf("final array, new length: %d\n", size0);
  show_array(array, size0);
}
```